# How to create a List of Map objects

Tags: apex, map

Is it possible to create a list of map objects? Here is what I am currently trying:

```
public List<Map<String, Integer>> slaMap = 
  new Map<String, Integer>[] {
    new Map<String, Integer> {'P1'=>30, 'P2'=>30},
    new Map<String, Integer> {'P1'=>60, 'P2'=>60},
    new Map<String, Integer> {'P1'=>120, 'P2'=>120},
  };
```

I can accomplish it using this method:

```
public List<Map<String, Integer>> slaMap = new List<Map<String, Integer>>();
slaMap.add(new Map<String, Integer> {'P1'=>30, 'P2'=>30});
slaMap.add(new Map<String, Integer> {'P1'=>60, 'P2'=>60});
slaMap.add(new Map<String, Integer> {'P1'=>120, 'P2'=>120});
```

However, I am wondering if it is possible using something similar to the first syntax I listed.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
List <Map<String, Integer>> a = new List <Map<String, Integer>> {
 new Map<String, Integer>{'p1'=>10, 'p2'=>10}, 
 new Map<String, Integer>{'p1'=>20, 'p2'=>20}
};
```

Comment: You beat me to it.

Comment: Good luck next time ;)

Comment: The reason why: you can't construct an array of collections using the [] syntax. Why not? Who knows, but that's the way it's done. Also, lists can't have a terminating comma.